# web scraping to csv project problems

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to make an app that scrapes my top ten favorite space related stock prices. but

- I have some trouble with my code and I'm new to scraping.
- Once I get this to work, I want to put it into a csv file
- and make a bar graph with it, I would love some help and suggestions.
- Also Im doing this in Anaconda :

My code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
#grequests is a unique library that allows you to use many urls with ease
#must install qrequest in annacode use : conda install -c conda-forge grequests
#if you know a better way to do this, please let me know
import grequests

#scraping my top ten favorite space companies, attempted to pick companies with pure play interest in space


urls = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GILT/', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LORL?p=LORL&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/I?p=I&.tsrc=fin-srch' , 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VSAT?p=VSAT&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/RTN?p=RTN&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UTX?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TDY?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ORBC?ltr=1', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPCE?p=SPCE&.tsrc=fin-srch', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BA?p=BA&.tsrc=fin-srch',]  
unsent_request = (grequests.get(url) for url in urls)

results = grequests.map(unsent_request)


def  parsePrice():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html")
    price=soup.find_all('div',{'class':'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="52">4.1500'})[0].find('span').text
    return price

    #Trying to figure out how to add this 
    # Random delay
    duration = random.uniform(1, 4)
    print('Random delay for %.2f seconds' % duration)
    time.sleep(duration)

    print('Scraping website for', urls)
    urls = hrefs[stock]
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

After this I'm getting this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-17-834b9d6c20e5>", line 3
    duration = random.uniform(1, 4)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

while True:
    print('current stock price: '+str(parsePrice()))

#add to csv file 
df_indu = pd.DataFrame(
    L['Top Ten Space Stocks'],
    columns=['stock name', 'stock price', 'date of listing'])
df_indu.to_csv('spacestocks.csv', index=False, sep='|')
```

SO here is my whole program that I have so far. Im trying to add a time delay and scrape the stock prices of all those stocks to place in a csv file to graph... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code indents at your `parsePrice()` function definition. At the end of your function you state `return price` thus ending the function definition. Now your following code should no longer be indented. This is why you get the unexpected indent error for everything after that.

Comment: You are technically both right and wrong. The error originates from the comment he has (`#Trying to figure out how to add this`) -- the Anaconda interpreter is seeing it as resetting indentation. What you are wrong on is that `return price` has any influence on it. Technically you can have `return` anywhere in a function, and as long as its intended right, it won't matter.

Comment: @felipe That is wrong. Python does not care about the indentation of blank lines or lines that have only a comment. You can easily test this for yourself at the REPL. The point of the answer is that the code following `return` is presumably intended to be outside the function, so it should not be indented. But the **error occurs** because of mixed spaces and tabs, *in a 2.x environment* that does not detect this as a `TabError`.